# Oracle - How to find tables where the data in the table are changing

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for an Oracle sql query that can tell me the names of tables and possibly columns for which the data in the tables has changed in a specified time period.

Actually I'm looking for the table underlying workflow processes (the one with the human name of the process, not the code) in Oracle Applications, but can't for the life of me find it. So I figured it would be nice to create a new process and then check which tables have changed, and find it that way.

Doing a Gather Schema Statistics run and then a table change with:

```
select *
from   ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS
where  table_owner not in ('SYSTEM', 'DBSNMP', 'SYS', 'CTXSYS')
order  by timestamp desc
```

also does not work.

Also tried this:

```
select name, max(ora_rowscn)
from   sys.obj$
group  by name
order  by 2 desc
```

But it doesn't seem to pickup my changes.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `Change Data Capture` ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm

Comment: Seems like CDC would require you to know the table names.

Comment: you could try enabling trace for your oracle apps sessions, then mine the trace files, or i'd look for a data model - or even better, ask your question on the OTN forum for your Oracle Apps...someone here can probably help you better https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-applications

Comment: The change I do is from Oracle Workflow not the application. Can you enable trace files for Oracle Workflow?

Comment: Did you run `begin DBMS_STATS.FLUSH_DATABASE_MONITORING_INFO; end;` before looking in `ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS`?

Comment: Did now. Still getting nothing.